# How to fit a 2D Feature in MLP Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have this pandas dataframe `ModelCFL = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data_case', 'length'])`

I fill this Dataframe with my csv files:

```
cases = ['0', '250']
    for i in range(0, len(cases)):
    cases_data = pd.read_csv(cases[i] + '.csv', header=0, delimiter=";")
    cases_data.dropna(inplace=True)
    parser_data = cases_data['current'].tolist()
    ModelCFL.at[i, 'data_case'] = parser_data
    ModelCFL.at[i, 'length'] = cases[i]
```

Then I am creating my X and Y variables:

```
X = ModelCFL.loc[:, 'data_case'].to_list()
Y = ModelCFL.loc[:, 'length'].to_list()
```

The .csv files are like this: (dummy dataset)

[image]

[image]

My problem is that when I run:

```
Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=1)
CFL_ANN = MLPRegressor(max_iter=300, activation="relu", hidden_layer_sizes=(25, 25))
CFL_ANN.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
CFL_ANN_predict = CFL_ANN.predict(Xtest)
```

I get the following error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '300,300,300'

My problem is that I cannot parse it into a float because my variable is a list of values (2D feature)

How can I make MLPRegressor understand that my variable is a list of numbers? Like that it can understand that my variable looks like this:

[image]

Comment: can you split the datacase column into individual columns? like X1, X2, X3?

Comment: No, the because with the real data I would have X1.... X60000+ (the list values will be a lot)

Comment: You misunderstood the question. What he means is you need to make X as the input of 3 columns X1, X2, X3, where each row is one line in your CSV file.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting it, each csv file only has 1 row. A long row. So why X1, X2 and X3? Thanks for the help :)